# How to get image from datatable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a data table called `dtchild` and it contains a column named `FILE_CONTENT`. In my data table, `FILE_CONTENT` data is stored as a `byte[]` array.

How to retrieve `FILE_CONTENT` data from the data table and convert it into an image?

Comment: No. Firstly I need to get data from my datatable

Comment: You have 2 problems, query database, convert bytes to image, which one are you suck on. **Pro Tip** don't say both...

Comment: Do you want to save that image on your local drive?

Comment: I dont want to save that image. Images are saved in the db. I just want to display those images

Comment: Where do you want to display them? can you be more specific please?

Comment: `var img = (Image)new ImageConverter().ConvertFrom(bytes);`

Comment: I want to display image on browser . I need image from the datatable.

Comment: Browser? What the browser has to do with the question? ASP.NET MVC? ASP.NET WebForms? WPF? WinForms? ... Please add tags and also take a look at [ASK].

Answer (score 0):

// bytes is the `byte[]` array of your file content :

```
using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
{
    var Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering you want to show image in asp.net web forms

Try this code , on aspx page :

```
     <img id='yourID' runat='server'/>
```

On CS page

```
      byte[] Binary = (byte[])(dt.Rows[0]["Your column"]);
      string base64string= Convert.ToBase64String(Binary, 0, Binary.Length);
      yourID.Src = "data:image/jpg;base64," + base64String;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
byte[] imgData = (byte[])dt.Rows[0]["Photo"];
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imgData);
Image img = Image.FromStream(ms);
pictureBox1.Image = img;
```